# how to select a period of time in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to make a MySql selection for a period of time. but i didn't figure it out how to make it correctly.

this is what i tried

`SELECT * FROM rapoarte WHERE DATE(ziua) BETWEEN 2010-01-12 AND 2011-01-14`

Can you please help?

thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: what is the type of the field ziua?

Comment: the type of the ziua field is Date. but it worked fine with the quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM rapoarte WHERE DATE(ziua) BETWEEN "2010-01-12" AND "2011-01-14"
```

Answer (score 6):

If performance is an issue I would avoid using `DATE` in this way as it will prevent efficient usage of an index and will result in a full scan. For small tables this might not be a problem but if your table is large you will probably find that this gives better performance:

```
SELECT *
FROM rapoarte
WHERE ziua >= '2010-01-12'
AND ziua < '2010-01-15'
```

Comment: +1 This is the better method, however the first > must be a >=. In addition, I don't think the "00:00:00" is necessary.

Comment: @AndreKR: Yes, you are right about the >=. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: @MarkByers I didn't get the performance part. How can performance get affected using Date? reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382892/whats-mysqls-between-performance-over