# What's mysql's "BETWEEN" performance over..?

Tags: mysql, between

Is there any better performance when querying in (particularly) mysql of the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `unix_date` BETWEEN 1291736700 AND 1291737300
```

over:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `unix_date` >= 1291736700 AND `unix_date` <= 1291737300
```

or BETWEEN syntax is just being substituted with the second sql?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As I recall, there's no difference. But see for yourself if:

```
explain plan for 
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `unix_date` BETWEEN 1291736700 AND 1291737300
```

and:

```
explain plan for
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `unix_date` >= 1291736700 AND `unix_date` <= 1291737300
```

produce the same plans.

Answer (score 32):

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

> - `expr` BETWEEN `min` AND `max`
>
> If `expr` is greater than or equal to `min` and `expr` is less than or equal to `max`, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0. **This is equivalent to the expression (`min` <= `expr` AND `expr` <= `max`) if all the arguments are of the same type.** Otherwise type conversion takes place according to the rules described in Section 11.2, “Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation”, but applied to all the three arguments.

So it really is just syntax sugar.

Answer (score 8):

`BETWEEN` shows clearer intent and reads better (something SQL set out to do).

Comment: While you are right, it does read better, the question was about the performance. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Jools - In this example, the BETWEEN statement is 10 less bytes... so there's your performance :)

Answer (score 5):

The three following statement will produce the same result:

1. `i BETWEEN x AND y`
2. `x <= i AND i <= Y`
3. `i >= x AND i <= Y`

But in  configuration 3 mysql might (depending on your indexes) use different indexes: order matters and you should be testing with EXPLAIN query to see the difference