# What is ActiveRecord/SQL performance of queries between two dates

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, activerecord

There are two ways that I know that you can fetch results in Rails through AR, here are two example queries that return the same results but make different SQL queries.

A)
`where("created_at < ? and created_at > ?", week1, week2)`

B)
`where(:created_at => week1..week2)`

The second one (besides being nicer looking, IMHO) also creates a `BETWEEN` type SQL query, while the first one is pretty much self explanatory.

Which one is better performing, or better for any other reason besides style?

Comment: it should be B) where(:created_at => week2..week1)

Comment: Can you give a reason? That's what I'm looking for, reasons please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be little bit db specific ..as rails generate these queries for them

```
A) WHERE (created_at < '2012-05-29 13:14:50' and created_at > '2012-05-28 15:14:50')

B) WHERE (`questions`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2012-05-28 15:14:39' AND '2012-05-29 13:14:39')
```

:) You should not worry much about it ...as long as you are using ActiveRecord

have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382892/whats-mysqls-between-performance-over)

Answer (score 1):

I think B is what most people would go for because they write less code and don't have to think about `SQL` query at all.

For performance, I think it should be the same. MySQL just provides a nicer way to do a where clause in a range value.