# Which datetime range scan performs better: BETWEEN or comparison operators

Tags: mysql, performance, datetime, between

I'm using Mysql 5.6 and I run many queries based on datetime.

When scanning records in a table in a certain datetime range, which one do you think runs faster between two queries below, especially when comparing value is `string type`?
Of course, datetime column is indexed.

A. using `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users 
WHERE created_at  BETWEEN '2018-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-11-30 23:59:59'
```

B. using `>=`, `<=`

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users 
WHERE created_at >= '2018-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-11-30 23:59:59' >= created_at
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's mysql's "BETWEEN" performance over..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382892/whats-mysqls-between-performance-over)

Comment: I read the replies on the question you mentioned, but the question was the case when setting comparing values as an integer.

Comment: It really does not matter whether it is an integer. Any good optimizer should take care of this and handle this the best way possible whether using `between.. and` or `> / <=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both queries are identical and there is absolutely no difference**. [Quote from SQL92 specs](https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt):

> ```
> 6) "X BETWEEN Y AND Z" is equivalent to "X>=Y AND X<=Z".
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it won't matter, but you can benchmark those with the [SHOW PROFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profile.html) option of MySQL. The basic usage gives you the duration of different statuses when processing the query, but there are more specific measures for different resources.

set the profiles on for the session:

```
SET profiling = 1;
```

Run your first version of the query in a very large dataset and check the profile with:

```
SHOW PROFILE;
```

Then, repeat the same steps for the other query.

I'd repeat this process several times and is possible during different days to be sure other processes running on the server don't affect much your results and final comparison.

This is an example of what I've got with a local test I did, but only to show what figures you get from the `SHOW PROFILE`. The table was small and I only run the queries once each. ;)

- for `BETWEEN` filtering

  ```
  starting    0.000045
  checking permissions    0.000005
  Opening tables  0.000011
  init    0.000020
  System lock 0.000006
  optimizing  0.000017
  statistics  0.000011
  preparing   0.000008
  executing   0.000003
  Sending data    0.000535
  end 0.000004
  query end   0.000006
  closing tables  0.000006
  freeing items   0.000015
  cleaning up 0.000009
  ```
- for `>= AND <=` filtering

  ```
  starting    0.000048
  checking permissions    0.000004
  Opening tables  0.000010
  init    0.000025
  System lock 0.000005
  optimizing  0.000010
  statistics  0.000011
  preparing   0.000008
  executing   0.000003
  Sending data    0.000531
  end 0.000004
  query end   0.000005
  closing tables  0.000005
  freeing items   0.000016
  cleaning up 0.000008
  ```